# Computational error with lmerTest and undefined columns selected when using mixed()

Tags: r, mixed-models

I want to fit a mixed effects linear regression. The dependent variable is acceptability judgments on a 4 point rating scale (Totally unacceptable to Totally unacceptable). These judgments have been assigned a numeric value (1, 2, 3, 4) and that vector was centered and scaled.

I call the model with the following code:

```
ln1 = lmer(RatingNorm ~ Group + ProfScore + RegularityInflectedForm + RegRhyme*SimilarityReal + Tense + VerbClass + (1|SubjectID) + (1|Infinitive), data=AJT1)
```

Then try for p values with:

mixed(ln1, AJT1)

No error messages have appeared following fitting the model. Using mixed() from the afex package to get p values gives a strange error message.

```
Fitting one lmer() model. [DONE]
Calculating p-values. 
anova from lme4 is returned
some computational error has occurred in lmerTest
Error in `[.data.frame`(anova_table, , c("NumDF", "DenDF", "F.value",  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

This has repeated itself when I call the same model using the lmerTest package. I have also tried simpler models with only one of the fixed effects (just Group or just Tense, which are categorical, and just ProfScore, which is continuous), as well as using only one of the two random effects. The same error always repeats. However, I am able to use anova(model) to see p values. I would like to know why I cannot use mixed() successfully in this case. I also have the most recent version of R installed, and am not seeing any posts showing similar errors for this kind of scenario.

Here are links to code and dataset:

- [R code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_IggMRaTQs9N1k1WGNGam5zR2s)
- [Dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_IggMRaTQs9ODViM0dRRWlGNUk)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a similar problem trying to use piecewiseSEM in R. It runs fine if I eliminate the mixed model portion of the DVpopStand model (and use lm).

> dumpster = list(
>
> lmer(DVpopStand ~ Treatment + Site + (1|fLine/fBowl)),
>
> lmer(centroidStand ~ Treatment + Site+ (1|fLine/fBowl)),
>
> lmer(Crush ~ Treatment + Site + centroidStand + DVpopStand + (1|fLine/fBowl))
> )
>
> Model.result = sem.fit(dumpster, data= F1culled)

And get the error message:

> summary from lme4 is returned
>
> some computational error has occurred in lmerTest
>
> Error in `[.data.frame`(ret, 3:4) : undefined columns selected